# Closed form for a finite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

Define $$f_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\sum_{s_1=0}^n a_{n,s_1,s_1,s_1,s_1} x_1^{s_1}x_2^{s_1}x_3^{s_1}x_4^{s_1}+\sum_{s_i\neq s_j, \forall i\neq j,s_i\in[0,n]} a_{n,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} x_1^{s_1}x_2^{s_2}x_3^{s_3}x_4^{s_4} $$ where $x_i\in (0,1)$ $\forall i$ and $$a_{n,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} =(-1)^{s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4}\binom{n}{s_1}\binom{n}{s_2}\binom{n}{s_3}\binom{n}{s_4}\binom{n+s_1}{s_1}\binom{n+s_2}{s_2} $$

> I need a closed form for $f_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$

We have the first sum as $$\sum_{s_1=0}^n a_{n,s_1,s_1,s_1,s_1} x_1^{s_1}x_2^{s_1}x_3^{s_1}x_4^{s_1}=\sum_{s_1=0}^n \binom{n}{s_1}^4\binom{n+s_1}{s_1}^2 (x_1x_2x_3x_4)^{s_1}$$
So we get [using Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28n+choose+r%29%5E4+%28%28n%2Br%29+choose+r%29%5E2+x%5Er%2C+r%3D0+to+n)

$$\sum_{s_1=0}^n a_{n,s_1,s_1,s_1,s_1} x_1^{s_1}x_2^{s_1}x_3^{s_1}x_4^{s_1}= \,_6F_5(-n,-n,-n,-n,n+1,n+1;1,1,1,1,1;x_1x_2x_3x_4)$$
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The $x_4$ and $x_3$ dependencies should be *mostly* removable as factors of $(1-x_3)^n(1-x_4)^n$. Similarly for $x_1,x_2$, but I don't know off the top of my head what $\sum_i \binom n i\binom{n+i}i x^i$ sums to. I say "mostly" because you will have to add in various cases for $s_i = s_j$ to get the full product. But figuring out what the sum of the $s_i = s_j$ cases are may be more approachable than your original sum.

Comment: One other comment: Technically, the definition you give for $f$ *is a closed-form*. It involves merely a finite number of arithmetic operations to calculate. I get what you actually mean, but I am curious why you feel a closed form is needed. If one can be found using only simple functions, then that could make calculation much easier. But I doubt $_6F_5$ will be particularly easier to calculate than what you already have.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot for your comment. It was useful.